# HTTPModule which inherits from a basemodule is not being executed

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httpmodule

I have a BaseHTTPModule class which implements IHTTPModule, and a ChildHttpModule class that inherits BaseHTTPModule.

I configured my web.config file by adding the ChildHttpModule as a module within the system.webserver section.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="SecurityModule" type="Humana.ApplicationBlocks.Security.HttpModules.SecuredLogonsSecurityModule"/>
        <add name="SessionManagement" type="Humana.ApplicationBlocks.UIProcess.SessionManagementModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

However, when I run my application, ChildHttpModule is not getting executed. I am using IIS7.0 with integrated mode.

Do I need to do any further configuration for this?

Comment: Could you provide your configuration in your question? Which kind of IIS you're using, I presume > 7.0? Are you running IIS in integrated or classic mode? Could you provide the implementation of BaseHTTPModule and ChildHttpModule?

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="SecurityModule" type="Humana.ApplicationBlocks.Security.HttpModules.SecuredLogonsSecurityModule" />
      <add name="SessionManagement" type="Humana.ApplicationBlocks.UIProcess.SessionManagementModule" />
    </modules>    
</system.webServer>
using IIS 7.0 in integrated mode.

Comment: Could you include the (at least Init method) code for Base- and ChildHttpModules into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SecurityModule and SessionManagement is a alias for ChildHttpModule the only thing I can come up with is that your missing the assembly in your type value. The "type" value is in the format of {class}, {assembly}.